# PHP calendar with dates --> distinct weeks and merging rows

Tags: php, html, merge, html-table

I am currently creating a calendar where you can see all users that are saved in the database for that day and the possibility to add an user per date.

I want to work with dates because I think it is easier to work with in the future.
So what I am doing: I save a date into the database combined to an userid.
While I am fetching the data from database into a table I am converting the dates to days and weeks and years. Just to see which day is at 2015/10/05.
So I get $day = Monday, $week = 41, $year = 2015
In the table I want to put the users to the matching day.

The calendar looks like this:

[image]

I am calling an if statement:

```
if ($day == 'Mon') {
// SELECT * FROM users WHERE datum=$date
// Fetch and echo the users name into that day
}
```

The database looks like this:

[image]

The weeks showed here in the database, maybe they can be used for a proper display? But I don't know I tried several things.

I am using this code for putting the database rows into a table:

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct(week),datum, van , tot FROM roosternew ORDER BY datum ASC";
$run_sql = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);
?>                   

<table class="table">
  <thead>
      <tr class="primary">
          <th width="5%"><center>Week</center></th>
          <th width="10%">Maandag</th>
          <th width="10%">Dinsdag</th>
          <th width="10%">Woensdag</th>
          <th width="10%">Donderdag</th>
          <th width="10%">Vrijdag</th>
          <th width="10%">Zaterdag</th>
          <th width="10%">Zondag</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql)) {
      echo $row['datum'].'test';
      $datum = $row['datum'];
      $van = $row['van'];
      $tot = $row['tot'];
      $tijd = $van.' - '.$tot;

      $date = new DateTime($datum);
      $week = $date->format("W");
      $dag = $date->format("D");
      $jaar = $date->format("Y");

      $newdate_ = new DateTime($datum);
      $newdate =  $newdate_->format('Y-m-d');

      $week_start = new DateTime();
      $week_start->setISODate($jaar,$week);

      $thisdate_ = $week_start->format('d-m');

      //Create plus button
      $plus_button =  ' <a href="../rooster/add_rooster.php?datum='.$newdate.'"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a><br/>';

      //Plus button

      $thisdate = '<div class="datetable"><div class="datetable">'.$thisdate_.'</div></div><br/>';

    ?>
      <tr>
          <td class="primary"><center><strong><?= $week; ?></strong><br/><?php echo $thisdate.'<h4><small>'.$jaar.'</small></h4>'; ?></center></td>
          <td>
            <?php 
            createPlusButton(0, $jaar,$week);
            if ($dag == 'Mon') {
                getScheduleAdmin($newdate);
            }             
            ?>
          </td>

          <td>
            <?php 
            createPlusButton(1, $jaar,$week);
            if ($dag == 'Tue') {
              getScheduleAdmin($newdate);
            }             
            ?>
          </td>

          <td>
            <?php 
            createPlusButton(2, $jaar,$week);
            if ($dag == 'Wed') {
              getScheduleAdmin($newdate);
            }             
            ?>
          </td>

          <td>
            <?php 
            createPlusButton(3, $jaar,$week);
            if ($dag == 'Thu') {
              getScheduleAdmin($newdate);
            }             
            ?>
          </td>

          <td>
            <?php 
            createPlusButton(4, $jaar,$week);
            if ($dag == 'Fri') {
              getScheduleAdmin($newdate);
            }             
            ?>
          </td>

          <td>
            <?php 
            createPlusButton(5, $jaar,$week);
            if ($dag == 'Sat') {
              getScheduleAdmin($newdate);
            }             
            ?>
          </td>

          <td>
            <?php 
            createPlusButton(6, $jaar,$week);
            if ($dag == 'Sun') {
              getScheduleAdmin($newdate);
            }             
            ?>
          </td>

      </tr>  
    <? } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The function getScheduleAdmin($newdate):

```
function getScheduleAdmin($newdate) {
  require('connect.php');

  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM roosternew WHERE datum='$newdate'";
  $run_sql2 = mysqli_query($conn , $sql2);                      

  while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql2)) {
    $id_rooster_users = $row2['idusers'];

    $sql= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE idusers='$id_rooster_users'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    $name = $row['name'];

    $color = $row['color'];
    $sql3 = "SELECT van,tot FROM roosternew WHERE idusers= '$id_rooster_users'";
    $sql3_run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
    $sql3_array = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3_run);

    $van_user = $sql3_array['van'];
    $tot_user = $sql3_array['tot'];
    $tijd_user = $van_user.' - '.$tot_user;
    echo '<a href="../rooster/edit_rooster.php?id='.$id_rooster_users.'&datum='.$newdate.'" style="font-weight:bold; color:'.$color.';">'.$name.'</a><br/>'.'('.$tijd_user.')';
    echo '<br/>';
  }
}
```

The problem is described in the first image (the calendar), it will show me more than once the week and they won't merge.
I dont know how to merge the weeks so that it will be :

[image]

Something like that.
And not like this (situation right now):

[image]

if anyone knows a better way of doing this, please tell me.